# prevent a column in a list from being changed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I have a field called **event log** where people update new information on the status of the task. Now what I want to do is, I want everyone to add information to this field, but once it is saved nobody should be able to edit this field. To make it more clear, If I write something on the field and I save it and then I go in to edit the field in the list, I should not be able to change what I previously added but I can add new information on that field.

Comment: You could accomplish this by turning on version control and setting the "event log" field to multiple lines of text with "Append Changes to Existing Text" set to Yes.

Comment: Is that functionality good enough for what you needed? If so, I'll probably add an answer below but include some information on how someone might do this with non-text fields.

Answer (score 0):

One of the standard SP description fields has an option to only allow additions.

The previous entries are not displayed on the editform but are displayed on the dqisplay form

Comment: Are you referring to the site columns?  (A warning for anyone else who thinks about trying this in 2010, the "Document and Record Management" Description field cannot be deleted using the UI)

Comment: Haven't used it in a while, but last time was indeed a Site Column in 2013; I presume you mean you can not delete entries. Deleting the column from the contenttype is possible... that I recall... at least... I think... too much wodka :-/ (its 22:00 here in the low countries.. just in case people think I drink at work)

Comment: I did in fact mean that it can't be deleted from the content type or from the list columns. This happens with a small collection of so-called "sealed columns," though I've never found a list of which columns are sealed. While it can't be deleted from the list settings or from Designer, it can be done through powershell... maybe it can be done through CSOM too, idk.